# James Olson, RIP (Andromeda Strain, Moon Zero Two, several tv scifi movies/series)

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

American actor James Olson passed away at age 91 on April 7, 2022.  On the big screen, he played prominent roles in the cult sci-fi films *The Andromeda Strain* (1971) and *Moon Zero Two* (1969).  He also had guest appearances on shows such as the original *Battlestar Galactica* and *Wonder Woman*, and had supporting roles in several made-for-tv science fiction and occult-themed movies.

[image: From The Andromeda Strain]

[image: Signed photo of Olson from Moon Zero Two]

Comment: PFC Olson also served his country with distinction as a Military Policeman during the 1950s.

Comment: I remember him as the villain it the TV movie "Paper Man".

Comment: very familiar-looking actor but i never could have told you his name.